# Genymotion virtual device got no IP adress

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, android, ip, htc

when I try to run HTC Evo 4.3 (or other devices, it doesn't matter) in Genymotion (2.3.0 x64) (with VirtualBox 4.3.10) on Ubuntu 14.04, I get:

[image: Error 31 : The virtual device got no IP address.]

`The virtual device got no IP address. The VirtualBox DHCP server has not assigned an IP address to the virtual device.`

My settings in Virtual Box are the following:

[image: Settings Virtual Box]
[image: Settings Virtual Box]

How can I assign an IP address to the device?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i have seen about that discussion maybe it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device

Comment: good idea but it didn't work for me…

Comment: Don't be confused - these IP settings are NOT in the "settings" but in File->Preferences->network

Answer (score 2):

The responsible thing that is assigning dynamic IPs for you is called DHCP server so you have to enable it to resolve this issue.

Try the following:

Open VirtualBox's Preferences and under Network section, check the adapter named "vboxnet0" in "Host-Only Networks", double click on it and make sure to apply the following configuration there.

6- Double click on that name and apple the following configuration

Adapter Tab:

- IPv4 Adapter: 192.168.65.1
- IPV4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0

DHCP Server Tab:

- Check "Enable Server"

  *HINT*: THIS RESOLVES YOUR PROBLEM, BUT OTHERS IS REQUIRED TO AVOID OTHER PROBLEMS
- Server Address: 192.168.65.100
- Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Lower Address Bound: 192.168.65.101
- Higher Address Bound: 192.168.65.255

Note: make sure you don't have any other adapter with the same configuration that might cause conflicts .. revise all of adapters in that section, "Host-Only Networks" I mean, and delete the same ones there.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems well researched. I'm sorry but I'm now successfully using [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) by Google. However, it is necessary to start the emulator like this: `android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd AVD_for_2_7_QVGA -dns-server 8.8.8.8 -verbose` (android-sdk-linux is the directory withe the SDK)

Comment: welcome, hope the answer is beneficial to community

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I got the same error. I reduced the memory below 50% of the total memory. And now it works.

Comment: This fixed it for me too. I had to do it twice though because the setting reverted back the first time for some reason..

Comment: Which memory setting exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was normally using my laptop connected to LAN. When I was using the Laptop without LAN(cable disconnected) this error came.

After un-ticking "Cabale Connected" check box in "Network -> Adapter 1", VM stared without any issue.

Comment: It works for me!